# My Fwrite wont work or it seems like my FILE wont work in Dev c++

Tags: c++, c

here is my code in my code I don't see the list outcome when I add some records in my file_pointer it seems like the fwrite doesn't work pretty well or there is some sort if mistake in my code and also when I put an add records then i tried to list it it wont show any record or i think the list doesn't work too well as well

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<windows.h>

struct {
       char studno[10];
       char name[80];
       char section[20];
       int age;
           }student[20];
       FILE *file_pointer;
       int t; 
       void add();
       void list();
       void gotoxy(int x, int y) 
{ 
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; 
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}      
      int main()
      {
         int choice;
         for(;;)
     {             

                gotoxy(35,5);
                printf("[1]Add Student Record\n");
                gotoxy(28,10);
                printf("[2]List Student Record\n");
                gotoxy(28,12);
                printf("[3]Exit\n\n");
                gotoxy(35,15);
                printf("Choice: ");
                scanf("%d",&choice);
                if(choice==1){
                add();
                system("cls");
                }
                else if(choice==2){
                list();
                system("cls");
                }
                else if(choice==3){
                exit(0);
}                
                }
                }
     void add()
     {
          char ans;
          int i;
              for(i=0;i<20;i++){
                               system("cls");
                                gotoxy(31,2);
                                printf("ADD STUDENT RECORDS\n\n");
                                gotoxy(31,5);
                                printf("\t\t\t\tRecord Number: %d\n\n",i+1);
                                gotoxy(3,7);
                                printf("Student Number: ");
                                scanf("%s",&student[i].studno);
                                 gotoxy(3,9);
                                printf("Name: ");
                                scanf("%s",&student[i].name);
                                gotoxy(3,11);
                                printf("Section: ");
                                scanf("%s",&student[i].section);
                                 gotoxy(3,13);
                                printf("Age: ");
                                scanf("%d",&student[i].age);
                                t++;

                                if((file_pointer=fopen("student.dat","w"))!=NULL)
                                {
                                                fwrite(student[i+1].studno,sizeof(student[i+1].studno),i,file_pointer);
                                                            gotoxy(31,18);
                                                printf("\nAdd another? [Y/N]: ");
                                                scanf("%s",&ans);
                                                if(toupper(ans)=='N')
                                                {
                                                                    fclose(file_pointer);
                                                                     i=20;
                                                                     break;
                                                system("cls");
                                                }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                printf("Error writing student.dat\n");
                                                fclose(file_pointer);
                                                               gotoxy(31,18);
                                                printf("\nAdd another? [Y/N]: ");
                                                scanf("%s",&ans);
                                                if(toupper(ans)=='N')
                                                {
                                                                     i=20;
                                                                     break;
                                                system("cls");
                                                }
                                                }

              }
              }
           void list()
              {
                      system("cls");
                    int i,x=0,y=8;
                    gotoxy(31,2);
                    printf("LIST STUDENT RECORD\n\n");
                     gotoxy(3,5);
                    printf("Record No.");
                     gotoxy(3,6);
                    printf("-------------");
                     gotoxy(19,5);
                    printf("Student No.");
                     gotoxy(19,6);
                    printf("-------------");
                     gotoxy(35,5);
                    printf("Name");
                     gotoxy(35,6);
                    printf("-------------");
                     gotoxy(59,5);
                    printf("Section");
                     gotoxy(59,6);
                    printf("-------------");
                     gotoxy(73,5);
                    printf("Age");
                     gotoxy(73,6);
                    printf("-------------");

                    for(i = 0;i<t;)
                    {
                    if((file_pointer=fopen("student.dat","r"))!=NULL)
                    {
                     fread(student[i+1].studno,sizeof(student[i+1].studno),i,file_pointer);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     printf("Error writing student.dat\n");
                     fclose(file_pointer);
                      gotoxy(x+3,y);
                     printf("      -%d-",i+1);
                    gotoxy(x+23,y);
                     printf("%s",student[i].studno);
                      gotoxy(x+35,y);
                     printf("%s",student[i].name);
                      gotoxy(x+59,y);
                     printf("%s",student[i].section);
                      gotoxy(x+73,y);
                     printf("%d",student[i].age);
                     y++;
                     }
                    fclose(file_pointer);
                    i=t;
                     }
                     getch();
                     }
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: What is `student`? How is it declared/defined? How is the structure defined?

Comment: student is the one im putting my records on this is how it is struct {
       char studno[10];
       char name[80];
       char section[20];
       int age;
           }student[20];
       FILE *file_pointer;
       int t; 
       void add();
       void list();
       void gotoxy(int x, int y)

Answer (score 0):

In `add()`,

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
   ...
   fwrite(student[i+1].studno,sizeof(student[i+1].studno),i,file_pointer);
   ...
}
```

for `i = 0`, `fwrite` writes an array of `0 * sizeof(student[i+1].studno)` bytes to block of memory pointed by file_pointer and at last iteration `i = 19` writes an array of `19 * sizeof(student[i+1].studno)` bytes which isn't what you intended.

Comment: Should idelete the if?

Comment: but it wont still show when i press number 2 to show the list off all of the student enrolled it seems like it is breaking in list aswell when i putted a record on file_pointer